# Change theme in ISO image

Tags: linux-mint, iso, theme, wallpaper

When I install a Linux or use the Live CD, it comes with a default theme (windows and icons) and wallpaper.

I want to modify the default theme and wallpaper to other that I'm going to choose, these themes are set probably in some file inside the ISO image. How could I find and modify that file in the ISO image?

I'm using Linux Mint 18 Xfce 32 bit.

Comment: watch http://www.remastersys.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [PinguyBuilder](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pinguy-os/files/ISO_Builder/)

> [PinguyBuilder](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/10/create-custom-ubuntu-iso-with.html) is a script which allows creating a customized Live CD/Live USB (remaster) of Ubuntu or Linux Mint, that can be used either as a distributable ISO or as a backup.